# How to write the code for a timer discord js bot (at the hour)?

Tags: javascript, timer, discord, bots

I want a bot that will send a message every 1 hour and 10 minutes at the hour so once at 15:10 another at 16:10 and so on, how should go about doing that? please provide the code if possible // i tried using setInterval but i would have to wait till the hour every time I tweak the code

Comment: Well, not identical but still looks deeply helpful for your case: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47548081/4636715

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `node-cron` to schedule the job to run at 10 past every hour.

```
const cron = require("node-cron");

cron.schedule("10 * * * *", yourFunction);
```