# How do I schedule a message from a Discord bot to send every Friday?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm very very new to programming and I'm trying to set up a basic discord bot that sends a video every Friday. Currently I have:

Index.js which contains:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
require("dotenv").config()

const token = process.env.token;
const { prefix } = require("./config.js");

const client = new Discord.Client();
const commands = {};

// load commands
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  commands[command.name] = command;
}

// login bot
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on("message", message => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  let cmd = commands[command];
  if(cmd)
    cmd.execute(message, args)
});

client.login(token);
```

and a commands folder which contains beeame.js and that contains:

```
module.exports = { 
  name: "beeame",
  description: "b",
  execute: (message) => {
    message.channel.send("It's Friday!", { files: ["./beeame.mp4"] });
  }
}
```

I have heard about cron jobs and intervals but I'm not sure how to add these to the code I currently have.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: "*I have heard about cron jobs and intervals but I'm not sure how to add these to the code I currently have*" What examples have you looked at? What part of implementation are you stumped on?

Comment: @Elitezen I have looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47548081/send-scheduled-message and also looked through: https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron but I'm pretty clueless on where to even start since a lot of the tutorials I'm seeing starts a project from scratch that is completely different from mine

Comment: Read through the documentation and fill in the blanks. If you need to, copy the entire example then tweak it to fit into your project

Answer (score 1):

Nate,

Here's some basics, to get you started.  Your existing project you showed, sets up your bot to handle messages whenever they arrive.  Everything there stays as is.  You want to add a new section to deal with the timers.

First, here's a snippet of a utility file having to deal with Cron Jobs:

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const job = new CronJob('* * * * *', function() {
    const d = new Date();
    console.log('At each 1 Minute:', d);
});
job.start();
```

***the thing to study and pay attention to is the '* * * * *' area.  You will want to understand this, to set the timing correctly.***

so replace the console logging with your messages, set your timing correctly and you should be good to go.  The other thing to remember is that wherever your bot is running, the time zone might be different than where you (or others are)...so you might need to adjust for that if you have specific time of day needs.

Edit:
Based on subsequent questions....and note, I didn't set the time right.  you need to really do more research to understand it.

```
const cron = require('cron').CronJob;
const sendMessageWeekly = new cron('* * * * *', async function() {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(server_id_number);

    if (guild) {
        const ch = guild.channels.cache.get(channel_id_number);
        await ch.send({ content: 'This is friendly reminder it is Friday somewhere' })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    }
});
sendMessageWeekly.start();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! For the console logging part you mentioned, do I replace whatever is in the parentheses for console.log with whatever I want my message to be? Such as: "It's Friday!", { files: ["./beeame.mp4"] }

Comment: you'll want to know what guild, what channel, you want to send a message to....you already have the command in your original question: message.channel.send("It's Friday!", { files: ["./beeame.mp4"] }); you'll just need to be able to find the right guild and right channel.  Lots of places to look on the internet for finding channels from your bot.  (replace the entire console.log line with your channel.send)

Comment: Ah of course! I can find the guild and channel IDs no problem. I'm just not sure what to do with them or how to make the Cron job run the message.channel.send command.

Comment: gave you pretty much everything you need....code answer edited.